# What does this WPF binding mean?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have this sample code:

```
<ControlTemplate Content="{Binding .}"/>
```

What does the point mean here relating to the binding?

Comment: I also think it  is strange. Is is exists in WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` (period) of the binding refers to the binding path, and simply tells it to bind to the current source (i.e. inherited DataContext).

From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx):

> Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current source. For example, Text=”{Binding}” is equivalent to Text=”{Binding Path=.}”.

Also note that `Path=` can be omitted if Path is the first parameter, so your code means exactly the same. I tend to prefer just the `{Binding}` syntax, though it's up to you.